# Каково назначение оператора with в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, менеджер-контекста

`with` - оператор контекстного менеджера.

Как я понимаю, он юзается, чтобы закрыть или остановить после обработки те процессы, которые были открыты, например: открыл файл через `with` оператор можешь не беспокоиться о его закрытий.

Также и с сокетам, можно открыть через контекстный менеджер и не закрывать.

Есть ли еще какие нибудь примеры? Или все таки я еще не понимаю назначение этого оператора?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем смысле, контекстный менеджмент - это система управления ресурсами. Она позволяет выполнять какие-то действия при начале работы с ресурсом и какие-то действия при окончании работы с ним автоматически. Кроме того, контекстный менеджер так же, как и обычная подпрограмма, ограничивает область видимости переменных, инициированных внутри контекстного менеджера.
Классический случай - операции открытия файла

```
with open('a.file', 'a') as g
....
```

Здесь само открытие файла указано в явном виде. Однако, python, позволяет пользователю самому менять поведение контекстного менеджера, определив его в методах `__enter__()` и `__exit__()` пользовательского класса.

Например, так, как описано [у Кнуппа](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/):

```
class File():

    def __init__(self, filename, mode):
        self.filename = filename
        self.mode = mode

    def __enter__(self):
        self.open_file = open(self.filename, self.mode)
        return self.open_file

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.open_file.close()

files = []
for _ in range(10000):
    with File('foo.txt', 'w') as infile:
        infile.write('foo')
        files.append(infile)
```

То есть, здесь контекст менеджер сам обрабатыват открытие файла и возвращает его дескриптор непосредственно в тело `with`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например в библиотеке для работы с базами данных `sqlalchemy` оператор `with` используется для работы с сессиями.

А вообще, для любого вашего класса вы можете описать логику работы с `with` с помощью специальных методов `__enter__` и `__exit__`.

То есть каждый раз, когда вы написали класс, для объектов которого логично выполнить некоторые подготовительные или заключительные действия при начале/окончании работы с этим объектом, то можно попробовать реализовать для вашего класса поддержку менеджера контекстов.

Подробнее можно почитать здесь:

https://pythonz.net/references/named/with/

https://pycoder.ru/python-with-statement/

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, с версии Python 3.10.0b1 допускаются множественные выражения в контекстных менеджерах такого вида:

```
with (open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2):
    ...
```

https://bugs.python.org/issue12782

Comment: С 3.1. https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/compound_stmts.html#with.